# jCarousel display nothing if only one item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-tabs, jcarousel

I've developed one page using jCarousel within jQuery ui Tabs.
Following page is what I got:
http://knowledge.teldap.tw/knowledgeFB/my_creation/?fid=668330535

Problem is:
If you click the 3rd tab (only one item), you'll find nothing unless you click the left arrow to navigate. It's  weird because one the 1st tab ( more than one items) everything is normal and visible.

Can anyone find out what I've missed? Because I've struggled on this for several hours. 
Thanks!

Comment: Emilio, did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the width of your carousel image has not been adjusted properly

In your jquery,put scroll 1

```
 jQuery('#listelements').jcarousel({
                  scroll : 1,
```

And also adjust the height of the container

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango1 .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
    width: 1200px;
    height:630px;
    margin-left://adjust margin left here

}
```

You may have a look on this [carousel example](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/05/hello-syntaxhighlighter-function.html)

Comment: I tried to modify the height of the container. Still the same.